# Guess the number of a liar

Tags: game-theory

Sue picks a number from 0 to 3.

Tom asks questions about the number, with yes/no answers.  For example, "Is it odd" or "Is it 3?"

If Sue picked X, she is allowed to lie at most X times.  For example, if she picked zero, she must always tell the truth.  If she chose any other number, she can decide each question whether to lie, until she runs out of lies, after which she must tell the truth.

Tom wants to minimize the average number of questions.  Sue wants to maximize it.

I think Sue's best strategy is random.  Sometimes choose $0$, sometimes tell the truth when she doesn't have to.  What is her strategy, and how many questions does Tom need on average?

Wei Hua Huang posed this in rec.puzzles newsgroup twenty years ago.  I think we solved the worst-case number of questions, but not the average.

EDIT:

To compare, suppose Sue can pick 0 or 1, and may lie once if she picks 1.

Tom asks 'Is it 1?'.  Suppose Sue says no.  If she picked 1, then she has used up her lie.  So, whether Sue picked 0 or 1, she has no lies left.  Tom asks 'Is it 1?' again, and will get a correct answer.

Suppose Sue says yes to Tom's first question.  She can't say yes if she picked $0$, so
Tom now knows Sue picked $1$.

So Sue's best strategy is to say no, and it will take Tom two guesses.

Comment: When the game ends?

Comment: When Tom is certain of Sue's card.  Does the edit help?

Comment: Where can we find the original puzzle (worst-case) and its solution?

Comment: I can sometimes find it.  In Google Groups, the subject was  "Guess my number", the group was rec.puzzles, Wei-Hwa Huang (who I misspelt earlier) asked it on 12 Oct 1999

Comment: In the case of only two numbers: 0 and 1, do you also think Sue's optimal strategy is random? I maybe wrong but picking the highest number seems to be a weakly dominant action for Sue, no?

Comment: Sue can choose 0 with any probability between 0 and 1; then answer 'no' every time.

Comment: The structure of the game needs to be made more clear. To simplify, suppose Sue can choose either 0  or 1 and Tom can only guess 0  or 1. In response to Tom's guesses, Sue can answer “Yes” or “No”. Suppose Sue chooses 0 at the first node. If Tom guesses 1, Sue must answer no, and If Tom guesses 0 Sue must answer yes. After each of these answers, the game must end immediately and the payoffs are realized, correct? Note, this sounds like a dynamic game of incomplete information.

Comment: No, because Tom still doesn't know if Sue chose 1 then lied; or chose 0 and told the truth.  He needs to ask the question again.  For the second question, if Sue chose 1, she has run out of lies, so Tom knows the second answer will be true.

Comment: So after Sue says “Yes” after Tom's guess was 0 there is an information set where the original choice by Sue could be 0 (true) or 1 (lie). Likewise, if Sue says “No” after Tom's guess was 1 there is an information set where Sue's choice could have been 0 (true) or 1 (lie). If Sue says “Yes” after Tom's guess was 1, then Sue's number has to have been 1. If Sue says “No” after Tom's guess was 0 then the number has to have been 1. Drawing the game tree should help.

Comment: I like to think of Tom's knowledge as a 2-vector, whose first entry is the number of lies Sue has left IF she chose 0, and second entry is the number of lies Sue has left IF she chose 1.  So he starts in state $(0,1)$ - or $(0,1,2,3)$ in the original problem.  If any component becomes negative, that choice has been eliminated.

Comment: I find it much easier to draw a game tree. When information sets are specified, it is easier to see where all the subgames are. That will help solve the game according to an equilibrium notion like subgame perfect nash equilibrium, or perfect bayesian equilibrium, which can be solved by the technique of backwards induction. Here are some notes that I think may be useful in this context: http://slantchev.ucsd.edu/courses/gt/05-extensive-form.pdf

Comment: My trouble with the $(0,1,2,3)$ case is that, with seven different possible questions, so 14 possible answers at each stage, I think there are thousands of nodes on the game tree.

Answer (score 1):

We can verify each answer by asking:

Is it true to say, that if you were lying in the last question XOR you lie in this question, then $1$ is equal to $0$?

The answer for that question will be 'YES', if Sue told the truth in previous question and 'NO', if she lied, no matter if she's lying or telling the truth in this question.

Then we have:

- Is it odd?
- [verification]
- Is it greater than 1?
- [verification]

Which gives us 4 questions to be sure about the number.

We can also use this method of verification to turn every 'Guess the natural number of a liar' to normal 'Guess the natural number' (number of questions is just doubled)